# Doubt regarding the dimension of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, spacetime-dimensions

I'm very unsure about all this business so please forgive any inaccuracies in my question.

Essentially what I'm having trouble understanding right now is how we "decide" the dimensionality of a manifold. For instance, take the 2-sphere, $S^2$. It's commonly used as an example of why more than one chart may be required to cover a manifold; in this example, a stereographic projection is used to map points on $S^2$ to a plane ($\mathbb{R}^2$). But couldn't we also just map points on $S^2$ to $\mathbb{R^3}$ using just one chart with the identity map, and say that $S^2$ is a three-dimensional manifold? Or, even map the points on the 2-sphere to $\mathbb{R}^1$, using an infinite number of charts, and thus call $S^2$ a one-dimensional manifold?

Basically I'm not sure if, in a manifold where we have charts $\phi_{\alpha}:U_{\alpha}\to \mathbb{R}^n$, the dimensionality of the manifold is given by $n$, since there is some ambiguity (at least I believe there is) as to what dimensionality of Euclidean space the charts are mapping points of the manifold to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the concept of charts might be leading you astray here. A simple, practical and intuitive way to define the dimension of a manifold is the number of numbers you would need to locate a point on that manifold. For the case of a sphere, you need two, commonly written as $\theta, \phi$. For $\mathbb{R}^3$, you need 3, $x,y,z$.

Sure you can embed $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but this doesn't mean $S^2$ has somehow become 3-dimensional. If we use spherical coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the $S^2$ is embedded via the following equation: $r=\text{const}.$ So although there are 3 coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$, one must be fixed to a constant to embed the $S^2$.

There is no direct connection between the number of charts and the dimensionality of the space.

If you map the points of $S^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$, then this is not an isomorphism between two manifolds--it is a projection. Many points on the $S^2$ are being mapped to the same point on the $\mathbb{R}^1$.

Comment: In other words, the map $U_\alpha\subset S^2\rightarrow U'_\alpha\subset \mathbb{R}^1$ is not one-to-one, which is by the definition of the manifold required for all such maps. (@OP, not you, Commander.)

Comment: Doesn't the second paragraph only apply to a sphere centered on the origin? So you don't really need to fix anything constant for the general case of a sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R^3}$, and could end up needing to use 3 numbers to locate points on the sphere.

Comment: So there's a distinction between embedding a sphere, and foliating the space with spheres. If I want to embed an $S^2$, I use the equation written above. I can foliate the space with spheres, which is essentially a fancy way of saying that spherical coordinates exist. But now I have 2 coordinates for where I am on the sphere, and another variable coordinate for "which sphere I'm on"--$r$. So this is a 3-dimensional manifold.

Comment: As for the map to $\mathbb{R^1}$ not being isomorphic, I think I see your point (or at least can't think of a way to construct a set of isomorphic maps that will do the trick), so I accept that you can't consider the sphere to be two-dimensional.

Comment: @PhysicsLlama: The origin is arbitrary. And embedding does not change the dimension of the manifold. What what we're really interested in are the local homeomorphisms. Do we need more than $2$ coordinates locally to map the sphere?

Comment: @SurgicalCommander Ah, cool, so if we have $S^2$'s embedded in different parts of $\mathbb{R}^3$, that constitutes a 3 dimensional manifold?

Comment: No, the whole point is that you must consider it to be two dimensional! Think of it this way. The sphere can be foliated by circles. Small circles near the poles, and a big one at the equator. If I take one of these circles and I blow it up it becomes $\mathbb{R}^1$, a 1-dimensional manifold. But I still have a whole 1-parameter family of circles that haven't been manipulated. So the dimension of $S^2$ is one more than the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^1$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant one-dimensional! :s

Comment: Ah, makes more sense. And to your question, yes, if you embed a 1-parameter family of $S^2$'s centered around each other (plus a point at the origin) then you have just foliated $\mathbb{R}^3$. Because you need a line of 2-dimensional manifolds, you end up with a 3-dimensional manifold.

Comment: Another thing I'm unsure of now, springing from this: roughly, we can say that a manifold is two-dimensional if we require two numbers to specify a point on the manifold, or if the charts of the manifold map the points to $\mathbb{R}^2$; how can we be sure that it's not possible to find a set of isomorphic maps that will do the job, in fewer dimensions? That is, how can we ensure that we're just not being clever enough in thinking of charts from open sets in the manifold to open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, in such a way as to minimize $n$?